# child state resolve injected in a parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this state confg :

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('projects', {
            url: '/projects',
            template : '<ui-view  autoscroll="true" autoscroll-body-top></ui-view>',
            abstract: true,
            title: 'Les projets',
            controller : 'ProjectController',
        }) .state('projects.add', {
            url: '/add',
            templateUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/gestionprojet/projects',
            title: 'Ajouter un projet',
        })
         .state('projects.detail', {
             url: '/detail',
             params : { projectId : null},
             templateUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/gestionprojet/detailProject',
             resolve : {
                 project: function (projectFactory, $stateParams) {
                     return projectFactory.getProject($stateParams.projectId);
                 },
                 projectTasks : function (projectFactory, $stateParams) {
                     return projectFactory.getProjectTasks($stateParams.projectId);
                 } 
             },
             title: 'Detail du projet',
        });
}
```

and in my controller :

```
angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.projects')
.controller('ProjectController', ProjectController);

function ProjectController($state, $stateParams, $log, $scope, projectFactory, taskFactory, project, projectTasks) { ... }
```

I get this error if I go to `project.add` :

> Unknown provider: projectProvider <- project <- ProjectController

How to resolve this ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your entire app config?  Need to make sure it's on the same module.  Also, is your controller in a different file?  If so, make sure it is being loaded into the browser.

Comment: I can't show you my entire config now but I'm sure that it's loaded in the same module and it's being loaded in the browser the problem is while loading for `project.add` state the vars of the resolve in the second child state are missing that's why I'm  getting this error and I don't know how to resolve that

Comment: if you go to project.detail, does it work?

Comment: Yes it does. Do I need to give the child state a different controller than the parent??

Comment: No you shouldn't have to.  The parent controller will have scope over both the children I believe.  If you want more specific scope for the children states, then you can do that.

Comment: That's why I don't understand, he it's not working.

Comment: Can you build a plnkr or fiddle to reproduce this?  It will be easier to debug that way.  I don't see anything that stands out right away.

Comment: it seems that injected resolved vars in child state cannot be injected in the parent controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested resolved vars cannot be injected into the parent controller. See [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3256)